# Uniswap v3 quanitiy that can be bought at price I calculated

Tags: solidity, uniswap

I've managed to get price of a pool using the function slot0() in UniSwapv3pool but how do I calculate what **quantity** can be bought at this price. In centralized exchange we can see the order book and do it. But in this case how can we do it?

```
  function slot0(
  ) external view returns (uint160 sqrtPriceX96, int24 tick, uint16 observationIndex, uint16 observationCardinality, uint16 observationCardinalityNext, uint8 feeProtocol, bool unlocked)
```

Price output :-

```
dai/eth =  2085.8642693686284
eth/dai =  0.000479417579890129
```

Comment: This could be similar to my question but is for uniswap v2: https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/107159/uniswap-v2-calculate-quantity-tradable-at-target-execution-price-in-solidity