# Uniswap V2 calculate quantity tradable to keep price above target price after trade

Tags: solidity, uniswap

Let's say the instantaneous price of `ETH/USDT` pair is 2000.

If I trade a lot of ETH for USDT, the price of the pair could decrease significantly due to my sell pressure, e.g. to `1950`.

Let's say I don't want the price to fall below `1950` after my trade. How can I calculate the max amount of ETH I can trade where this doesn't happen?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

**(It would be great if someone can verify if this answer is correct)**

As per the constant product formula,

```
x * y = k
```

where `x` and `y` is the quantity of two different tokens in the pool.

When we trade `a` amount of the first token for `b` amount of the second token, the constant product formula must be maintained, therefore:

```
(x + a) * (y - b) = k
```

The instantaneous price `p` of a pair is defined as the ratio of the two assets in the pool, i.e.

```
p = (y - b) / (x + a)
```

With some rearrangements, we get:

```
p(x + a) = (y - b)
```

We can then substitute this into the constant product formula:

```
(x + a) * p(x + a) = k
p(x + a)^2 = k
(x + a)^2 = k / p
x^2 + 2ax + a^2 = k / p
```

Of course `k` is just equal to `x * y`, therefore:

```
x^2 + 2ax + a^2 = (x * y) / p
```

Using [symbolab](https://www.symbolab.com/solver/simplify-calculator/solve%20for%20a%2C%20x%5E%7B2%7D%20%2B%202ax%20%2B%20a%5E%7B2%7D%20%3D%20%5Cleft(x%20%5Ccdot%20y%5Cright)%20%2F%20p) we find out:

[image]

as long as `a` is not zero.

---

**TL;DR:**

```
a = sqrt(pxy)/p - x
```

where `p` is the target price to be maintained and `x` and `y` are the quantities of the two tokens in the pool before the trade takes place.

(I should still verify that I didn't make any mistakes here).

---

**TEST CASE**

`X = 100 ETH, Y = 200,000 USD, P = 1950`

`a = sqrt(1950*100*200,000)/1950 - 100`

`=> a = ~1.274`

This seems right, because it is roughly half of [this similar question's answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/107165/67306).

---

**Calculating this in solidity**

It is awkward to calculate this in solidity.

Here is some sample code (please test this code before use in production, and also make sure it suits your needs):

```
function sqrt(uint x) returns (uint y) {
    uint z = (x + 1) / 2;
    y = x;
    while (z < y) {
        y = z;
        z = (x / z + z) / 2;
    }
}

function foo() {
    // pn => price numerator
    // pd => price denominator
    uint a = (sqrt((pn*x*y)/pd)*pd)/pn - x;

    // or in human readable terms:
    uint inputAmount = (sqrt((priceNumerator * inputReserve * outputReserve) / priceDenominator) * priceDenominator) / priceNumerator - inputReserve;
}
```